# How to reset "local" git repository?

Tags: git

I was trying to ignore some folders when pushing and ended up with only the `.gitignore` in the repository. Now want to "reset" my repository (by reset I mean to remove all the rules I applied and clean the commit area), so that I can add all my files and remove the folders I don't want after that. Any help?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You could just delete your .git folder and start again.

```
rm -rf .git
git init
```

This will leave the current .gitignore in place, which would still be followed by the new git repo. The .gitignore could be removed, or delete the contents so it is a blank file.

Comment: It's too bad that this is the only way of doing this. It would be great if there were a -f flag for `git init` to do it.

Comment: `rmdir /s /q .git` on windows

Comment: @Morgan Hey, I know I'm late, what does "-rf" stand for here? I can't find any help about that on the internet !

Comment: @DevMoutarde the -r is recursive (ie all sub folders and files), -f is force so will not ask about readonly files etc. more info see : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html

Answer (score 10):

If you want to create the repository again, then just remove the .git directory.

Comment: This, then you are free to start afresh with `git init`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need a clean history just remove the files from the repository and commit your changes. If you would like to revert to an earlier commit there is a git reset command

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Here is some more info [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit?rq=1)

Comment: Very bad idea since it pulls the code from remote repository.

Comment: WARNING to non expert users: be very careful with this command and only use when you are 100% sure about what you are doing. This deletes all untracked files and depending on your particular case could be really DESTRUCTIVE. Don't use lightly.

Comment: @rbndeveloper Of course you need to know what you are doing, but that applies to GUI users too, only press the buttons you understand. I use and recommend the command line tools and their man pages.